# An error occurs when running android apllication that implements tensorflow-lite on a specific device

Tags: android, tensorflow, opencl, tensorflow-lite

An error occurs when running android apllication that implements tensorflow-lite on a specific device.

ex)LG X4, LG Q52

I get an error when calling function -> tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);

This is my error log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 13469
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: Next operations are not supported by GPU delegate:
ADD: 
CONCATENATION: 
CONV_2D: 
EXP: Operation is not supported.
LEAKY_RELU: 
LOGISTIC: 
MAX_POOL_2D: 
MUL: 
RESHAPE: 
RESIZE_BILINEAR: 
SPLIT: Operation is not supported.
SPLIT_V: Operation is not supported.
STRIDED_SLICE: 
SUB: Expected 2 input tensor(s), but node has 1 runtime input(s).
First 61 operations will run on the GPU, and the remaining 144 on the CPU.
OpenCL library not loaded - dlopen fai
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:154)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:314)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV4Classifier.getDetectionsForTiny(YoloV4Classifier.java:421)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV4Classifier.recognizeImage(YoloV4Classifier.java:461)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV4Classifier.recognizeImage(YoloV4Classifier.java:50)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$3.run(DetectorActivity.java:304)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13469 SIG: 9
Connected to process 13858 on device 'lge-lm_q520n-LMQ520NOFAIMNHYEMS'.
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide additional details if it is working on other devices or how the model was generated. I have faced this error before. It is likely not device related. Based on the error log it seems you are [using this repository](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) for object detection task with yolov4 tflite model.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: Next operations are not supported by GPU delegate:
EXP: Operation is not supported.
SPLIT: Operation is not supported.
SPLIT_V: Operation is not supported.
```

Use `tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS` in `converter.target_spec.supported_ops` when converting **saved model** to tflite. Also in `build.gradle` use any one of the below,

`implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.3.0'`

`implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly'`.

This will increase apk size but this can solved with [selective build](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/reduce_binary_size) of `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar`.